# ¿Qué significa el "@" en el lenguaje java?

Tags: java

Quiero saber que función tienen los `@` en Java, los cuales están antes de sobrescribir un método o cuando se usa deprecated, del modo `@Override` o `@Deprecated`!!!

Comment: Me parece que esto tiene que ver con las *Java annotations* entonces te recomiendo este recurso *oficial* para que vayas revisando [java annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)

Comment: Agrega ejemplos de donde has visto esto para que tu pregunta sea más completa.Revisa [ask], no olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.